# How connect two projects

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a project named "slnAllForKids" in Visual Studio 2005. I have another project named "AFKLogin." There is a page called index.aspx in slnAllForKids. I want to redirect from index.aspx to home.aspx in AFKLogin when I click submit button in index.aspx. Can anybody help to redirect to another sln?

Answer (score 1):

Well... you're not really redirecting to another SLN, you're redirecting to another URL, right?  When your project is deployed, those two pages will have different URLs.

You can redirect to another URL using a line like

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/home.aspx")
```